# hierarchical taxonomy in permalinks? using same slug

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, slug, duplicates

I use permalink: `/%category%/%postname%.html` and want to have categories like this:

- Wheels

  - Mercedes
  - Toyota
- Brakes

  - Mercedes
  - Toyota

I want their URLs like this:

```
mysite.com/wheels/mercedes/mypost.html
mysite.com/brakes/mercedes/mypost.html
```

but the on the second try, the `mercedes` slug cannot be created, because it exists already.

Is there a workaround? One idea I had, is: change the rewrite rules link structure, as URLS were built according to category names, instead of "slugs".

Answer (score 0):

Slugs should be unique for each content type as they are a unique identifier of the content on the url side.

To overcome this limitation you can simply create two costume taxonomies one for wheels and one for brakes and have a mercedes in both of them.

Comment: And will i be able to publish posts under those taxonomies exactly like as under categories? as i want that posts permalinks were **Wheels/Mercedes/my-post-name** ?